# stop javascript till all respose from service arrive

Tags: javascript, google-api

I am calling google service multiple times in my javascript.

I want to stop executing further javascript till I get all the responses.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var schools =
    [
        'Abelsvej 98, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Almstoftevej 71, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Balstrupvej 35, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Ejlstrupvej 101, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Ejlstrupvej 101 C 101, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Ejlstrupvej 90 90, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Haraldsvej 7 7, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Løngangen 43 65, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Vetterslev Bygade 21 21, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Østergade 25, Høm 25, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Østergade 3, høm 3, 4100, Ringsted'
    ];


for (var r = 0; r < schools.length; r++) {

                (function (r) {
                    var address = schools[r][1];
                    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                                schoolsArray[r] = location.lat() + ', ' + location.lng();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                    , 1000 * (r + 1));
                }(r));

// other javascript stuff

</script>
```

I want that javascript should not go further till all responses has arrived.

Comment: You don't really want to stop JavaScript. That will freeze the UI, causing the browser to complain to the user that the script has stopped responding and ask the user if JavaScript should be completely turned off for that page.

Comment: but still it goes to next scripts & executes them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're experiencing here is the difference between asynchronous requests and synchronous JavaScript methodology.

The request to Google can take any length of time, and so you find that you have a callback as the second parameter in your `geocode()` method.

The best way to do this is to keep a count of how many responses you've had back, and in the callback method, you can add a function that will then run the rest of the JavaScript that you want to run when you have every response back.

There is no way to *stop* all JavaScript from running, you can merely tell some code to run when it has got every geocode response.

I am unsure why you have a `setTimeout()` in your code also.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var schools =
    [
        'Abelsvej 98, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Almstoftevej 71, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Balstrupvej 35, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Ejlstrupvej 101, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Ejlstrupvej 101 C 101, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Ejlstrupvej 90 90, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Haraldsvej 7 7, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Løngangen 43 65, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Vetterslev Bygade 21 21, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Østergade 25, Høm 25, 4100, Ringsted',
        'Østergade 3, høm 3, 4100, Ringsted'
    ];

var count = 0;

for (var r = 0; r < schools.length; r++) {
    (function (r) {
        var address = schools[r][1];
        var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
        setTimeout(function () {
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var location = results[0].geometry.location;
                    schoolsArray[r] = location.lat() + ', ' + location.lng();
                    count++;
                    if(count == schools.length){
                        doMoreJS();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        , 1000 * (r + 1));
    }(r));
}

function doMoreJS(){
    // Do more JS
}

</script>
```

Comment: setTimeout() is for google service otherwise you get OVER_QUERY_LIMIT error. Also can you suggest something for my code also.

Comment: Added some code. It checks if the count of returned items is the same as the length of schools. If so, it runs `doMoreJS()` where you should put your extra JS to run.